# Increment/Decrement/Print using multiple threads(Code review)

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronized

I was trying to write a code where multiple threads call methods on a shared object to increment/decrement/print a counter stored in it. What I also want are these numbers to vascillate between 0 and 8. That is the output might look like something below:
0123234567654566677877666655....

Can somebody look at what I have cranked out and give me some pointers on whether I am on the right track:

My shared object:

```
public class SyncObj{
        private int i;
        public synchronized void inc(){
                if(i<8)
                  i++;
        }
        public synchronized void dec(){
                if(i > 0)
                   i--;
        }
        public synchronized void print(){
                System.out.print(i);
        }
}
```

To prevent starvation on the print and to make sure every inc/dec gets printed, I can have a private variable called hasPrinted and rewrite the class as follows:

```
public class SyncObj{
            private int i;
            //Changed Boolean to boolean as Keith Randall pointed out
            private boolean hasPrinted = false;
            public synchronized void inc(){
                    if(i<8 && hasPrinted){
                      i++;
                      hasPrinted = false;
                    }
            }
            public synchronized void dec(){
                    if(i > 0 && hasPrinted){
                       i--;
                       hasPrinted = false;
                    }
            }
            public synchronized void print(){
                    System.out.print(i);
                    hasPrinted = true;
            }
    }
```

Can somebody go over the above snippet and review it for pitfalls and gotchas?

Thanks

Comment: I recommend you take a look at the [`java.util.concurrent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) package and use one of the mechanisms therein.

Comment: Should probably belong on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get used to using a queue for printing.

```
public class SyncObj {
  private volatile int i;
  private BlockingQueue<Integer> q = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Integer>();
  public synchronized void inc() {
    if (i < 8) {
      i++;
      q.add(i);
    }
  }
  public synchronized void dec() {
    if (i > 0) {
      i--;
      q.add(i);
    }
  }
  public void print() {
    for (Integer i = q.poll(); i != null; i = q.poll()) {
      System.out.print(i);
    }
  }
  private static volatile boolean stop = false;
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    final SyncObj o = new SyncObj();

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        while (!stop) {
          o.inc();
        }
      }
    }).start();

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        while (!stop) {
          o.dec();
        }
      }
    }).start();

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        while (!stop) {
          o.print();
        }
      }
    }).start();

    Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);
    stop = true;
  }
}
```

My output looks like this:

`1012345678765432101234567876543210123456787654321012345678765432101234567876543210123456787654321012345678`

Comment: I had a question about your print method. Is there a reason why you did for (Integer i = q.poll(); i != null; i =q.poll()){ System.out.print(i);} instead of System.out.println(q.take())?

Comment: The idea behind that I would presume would be because take() blocks all other operations whereas poll() is non-blocking?

Comment: @sc_ray If I had been able to do `while ( Integer i = q.poll() != null )` I would have done. Another alternative might be `q.drainTo(out)` but also not allowed. All I really want to do is print as many as is available at the time.

Answer (score 1):

`Boolean` -> `boolean`, no point in having an object instead of a primitive type.

Your first code is fine.  Your second code doesn't solve your requirements of preventing starvation or making sure every inc/dec gets printed.  Why not just have inc/dec print the value itself?

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to decouple the print from the dec/inc operation. Can you elaborate on why the second code will not make sure why every inc/dec gets printed? Wont the synchronized inc/dec flip the hasPrinted to false preventing any future incs/decs until the print has flipped the switch back to true after printing the value?

Comment: Certainly the last inc/dec might not get printed.  But from the callers' view, lots of inc/dec calls might not get printed, as they never even happen!  That's a bad API.

Comment: I do see how the inc and dec operations are getting suppressed by the print operation by hinging on the print operation. Ideally, the prints should go along with the incs/decs like you said. But suppose the directive is to decouple the print operation from the other operations,are there ways to structure the print without pausing the inc or dec?

Comment: I don't think so.  You can force the inc/dec to wait for the print using a semaphore, but if you want inc/dec to never pause you're out of luck.